# Unexpected end of JSON input while consuming Response body (self-defined HTTP codes)

Tags: javascript, express, http

I receive the following error when attempting to consume the [body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body) of a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) to a successful HTTP POST request:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.
```

This is the Express.js statement I used to send the response:

```
res.status(204).send(response)
```

Express's `res.send()` method automatically converts JavaScript objects to JSON upon sending. Regardless, `response` is explicitly being transformed into JSON via `JSON.stringify()` in its definition statement. So I am definitely *sending* JSON.

--

I am consuming the request on the client as follows:

```
fetch(URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data) // data is defined elsewhere in the file
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
```

However, whenever I attempt to read `response.body` to completion (see [Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body)), I receive the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.
```

Again, I have already confirmed that the data I *wish* to send from server to client is in JSON format. So, something is going wrong in-transit, as I am attempting to convert something to JSON that is not actually JSON.

I suspect the resource I wish to send is being misplaced in-transit, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Brother, you are sending the wrong status code actually 204 is used for when no content is access due to some reason when everything is ok then 200 status code is used.

```
 res.status(200).send(response);
```

updated answer after comment.

```
res.status(400).json({
            code : 400,
            message: "error message string"
        })
```

Comment: Yes - sorry, I should have specified: the code above was for one of 3 cases I had written for new user sign-ups: (1) failed INSERT - duplicate username, (2) failed INSERT - duplicate email, (3) successful INSERT. 

The code above was for one of the fail cases. I didn't want to use `200`, as the resource wasn't successfully created. However, I still wanted to return a specific error message to the client.

Comment: In case of an error, you can send the response in this way.
     
      'res.status(400).json({
                code : 400,
                message: "Error message string"
            })'
I also edit my answer you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that **I was self-defining my status code as 204.**

When HTTP status `204` is specified, only the ***headers*** of your request will be forwarded. No body content will be forwarded.

Recall that my original Express response was:

```
res.status(204).send(response)
```

By defining HTTP status `204`, I ensured that the `response` in `send(response)` would be discarded.

My issue was resolved by updating my response to:

```
res.send(response)
```